# Pandas: Difference between largest and smallest value within group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a data frame that looks like this

```
GROUP VALUE
  1     5
  2     2
  1     10
  2     20
  1     7
```

I would like to compute the difference between the largest and smallest value within each group. That is, the result should be

```
GROUP   DIFF
  1      5
  2      18
```

What is an easy way to do this in Pandas?

What is a fast way to do this in Pandas for a data frame with about 2 million rows and 1 million groups?

Answer (score 62):

Using @unutbu 's `df`

***per timing***
unutbu's solution is best over large data sets

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1], 'VALUE': [5, 2, 10, 20, 7]})

df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].agg(np.ptp)

GROUP
1     5
2    18
Name: VALUE, dtype: int64
```

---

[`np.ptp` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html#numpy.ptp) returns the range of an array

---

***timing***
**small `df`**

[image]

**large `df`**
`df = pd.DataFrame(dict(GROUP=np.arange(1000000) % 100, VALUE=np.random.rand(1000000)))`

[image]

***large `df`***
***many groups***
`df = pd.DataFrame(dict(GROUP=np.arange(1000000) % 10000, VALUE=np.random.rand(1000000)))`

[image]

Comment: For a long time I've been wondering why pandas doesn't have a range method. Good to know numpy has it.

Comment: Am I missing something here? It seems like the np.ptp method is only fastest in the "small df" case. In other cases, the .agg([max],[min]).diff(axis=1) method performed significantly better.

Comment: @HeavyBreathing you didn't miss a thing. I was providing an alternative solution yet validating another poster's solution.

Answer (score 32):

`groupby/agg` generally performs best when you take advantage of the built-in aggregators such as `'max'` and `'min'`. So to obtain the difference, first compute the `max` and `min` and then subtract:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1], 'VALUE': [5, 2, 10, 20, 7]})
result = df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].agg(['max','min'])
result['diff'] = result['max']-result['min']
print(result[['diff']])
```

yields

```
       diff
GROUP      
1         5
2        18
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised how much better this is than `agg(np.ptp)` especially over a large number of groups!

Comment: What if I want to do this for each of several columns, not just one ('VALUE')?

Comment: @CPBL: If you want to find the `min` and `max` for all the columns of `df` (per `GROUP`), then simply remove `['VALUE']`. That is, use `df.groupby('GROUP').agg(['max', 'min'])`. If you wish to find the `min`, `max` per `GROUP` for some but not all columns, restrict `df` first: `df[['GROUP','VALUE1','VALUE2']].groupby('GROUP').agg(['max','min'])`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a one-liner for getting the differences? (Not using np.ptp, since I actually want the signed difference from agg(['last','first']))

Comment: @CPBL: You could use `df.groupby('GROUP').agg(['last','first']).stack(level=0).diff(axis=1).unstack(-1)['last']`. But I don't find that particularly readable. Perhaps using 3 lines `result = df.groupby('GROUP').agg(['last','first'])`, `result = result.reorder_levels([1,0], axis=1)`, `result['last'] - result['first']` is better.

Answer (score 16):

***Note**: this will get the job done, but [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40184053/2074981) has faster methods.*

You can use `groupby()`, `min()`, and `max()`:

```
df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].apply(lambda g: g.max() - g.min())
```