# Pandas: count difference between dates

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have dataframe

```
ID   date
111   11-11-2016
111   14-11-2016
111   17-11-2016
222   24-11-2016
222   27-11-2016
```

I need to count difference between data to every ID.
I use

```
df['duration'] = df.groupby(['ID','date']).date.apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])
idx = df.groupby(['ID'])['duration'].transform(max) == df['count date']
```

But it returns wrong result.
How can I get desirable?
I need to get

```
ID   count date
111    6
222    3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['date'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
ID
111   6 days
222   3 days
```

Also possible with [`numpy.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html)

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['date'].agg(np.ptp)
ID
111   6 days
222   3 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `agg`'s built in `min` and `max`
[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40184053/2336654)

```
d1 = df.groupby('ID').date.agg(['min', 'max']).diff(axis=1)['max']

ID
111   6 days
222   3 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```