# Slicing Pandas rows with string match slow

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I basically want to learn a faster way to slice a Pandas dataframe with conditional slicing based on regex. For example the following df (there's more than 4 variations in the string_column, they are only for illustrative purposes):

```
index, string_col1, string_col2, value
0, 'apple', 'this', 10
1, 'pen', 'is', 123
2, 'pineapple', 'sparta', 20
3, 'pen pineapple apple pen', 'this', 234
4, 'apple', 'is', 212
5, 'pen', 'sparta', 50
6, 'pineapple', 'this', 69
7, 'pen pineapple apple pen', 'is',  79
8, 'apple pen', 'sparta again', 78
...
100000, 'pen pineapple apple pen', 'this is sparta', 392
```

I have to do Boolean conditional slicing according to the string_column using regex, while finding the indices with minimum and maximum in the value column, and then finally finding the difference between the min and max value. I do this by the following method, but it's SUPER SLOW when I have to match many different regex patterns:

```
pat1 = re.compile('apple')
pat2 = re.compile('sparta')
mask = (df['string_col1'].str.contains(pat1)) & (df['string_col2'].str.contains(pat2))
max_idx = df[mask].idxmax()
min_idx = df[mask].idxmin()
difference = df['value'].loc[max_idx] - df['value'].loc[min_idx]
```

I think to get one "difference" answer, I'm slicing the df too many times, but I can't figure out how to do it less. Furthermore, is there a faster way to slice it?

This is an optimization question since I know my code gets me what I need. Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: One can combine the regex into a single regex and then the mask is likely faster. patX=re.compile('(apple|sprata)'). Does this make it faster? Additionally, making a mask over the whole DataFrame to get the first index might not be the fastest.

Comment: I need to do two separate regex check for two different patterns for two different columns, so I'm not sure combining them into one regex and match across two columns is a good idea.

Comment: Looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183800/pandas-difference-between-largest-and-smallest-value-within-group

Comment: do you want idxmax for the string or the value column?  your code crashes for me in python3 but if I'm reading your code right idxmax is just taking the "alphabetical" max.  is that actually what you want?  sample output might be good here also.

Comment: Why the regex on these checks? Seems like you could just use `df['string_col1'].str.contains('apple', case=False)`, no? Seems like it would be faster than compiling regex patterns and using them.

Comment: I think you should provide an example or a skript which would create a typical test case.

Answer (score 1):

Pass each mask to next subset of dataframe, each new filtering happens on a smaller subset of the original dataframe:

```
pat1 = re.compile('apple')
pat2 = re.compile('sparta')
mask1 = df['string_col1'].str.contains(pat1)
mask = (df[mask1]['string_col2'].str.contains(pat2))
df1=df[mask1][mask]
max_idx = df1['value'].idxmax()
min_idx = df1['value'].idxmin()
a,b=df1['value'].loc[max_idx],df1['value'].loc[min_idx]
```

Comment: Can you explain why would this be faster?

Comment: because each new filtering happens on smaller subset of original dataframe

Comment: It is a sane idea, but will not help much if all patterns match

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to profile your example, but I'm actually getting pretty great performance on my synthetic data, so I may need some clarification. (Also, for some reason .idxmax() breaks for me whenever I have a string in my dataframe).

Here's my testing code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import random
import IPython
from timeit import default_timer as timer

possibilities_col1 = ['apple', 'pen', 'pineapple', 'joseph', 'cauliflower']
possibilities_col2 = ['sparta', 'this', 'is', 'again']
entries = 100000
potential_words_col1 = 4
potential_words_col2 = 3
def create_function_col1():
    result = []
    for x in range(random.randint(1, potential_words_col1)):
        result.append(random.choice(possibilities_col1))
    return " ".join(result)

def create_function_col2():
    result = []
    for x in range(random.randint(1, potential_words_col2)):
        result.append(random.choice(possibilities_col2))
    return " ".join(result)

data = {'string_col1': pd.Series([create_function_col1() for _ in range(entries)]),
        'string_col2': pd.Series([create_function_col2() for _ in range(entries)]),
        'value': pd.Series([random.randint(1, 500) for _ in range(entries)])}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pat1 = re.compile('apple')
pat2 = re.compile('sparta')
pat3 = re.compile('pineapple')
pat4 = re.compile('this')
#IPython.embed()
start = timer()
mask = df['string_col1'].str.contains(pat1) & \
       df['string_col1'].str.contains(pat3) & \
       df['string_col2'].str.contains(pat2) & \
       df['string_col2'].str.contains(pat4)
valid = df[mask]
max_idx = valid['value'].argmax()
min_idx = valid['value'].argmin()
#max_idx = result['max']
#min_idx = result['min']
difference = df.loc[max_idx, 'value'] - df.loc[min_idx, 'value']
end = timer()
print("Difference: {}".format(difference))
print("# Valid: {}".format(len(valid)))
print("Time Elapsed: {}".format(end-start))
```

Can you explain how many conditions you're applying? (Each regex I add only adds a roughly linear increase in time (i.e. 2->3 regex means a 1.5x increase in run time)). I'm also getting linear scaling on the number of entries, and both potential string lengths (the potential_words variables).

For reference, this code is evaluating in ~ .15 seconds on my machine (1 million entries takes ~1.5 seconds).

Edit: I'm an idiot and wasn't doing the same thing you were (I was taking the difference between values at the smallest and largest indices in the dataset, not the difference between the smallest and largest values), but fixing it didn't really add much in the way of runtime.

Edit 2: How does idxmax() know which column to select a maximum along in your example code?

Answer (score 1):

you can speed the logical comparison by a factor of 50 by not using `&` but `scipy.logical_and()` instead

```
a = pd.Series(sp.rand(10000) > 0.5)
b = pd.Series(sp.rand(10000) > 0.5)

%timeit sp.logical_and(a.values,b.values)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.31 µs per loop

%timeit a & b
1000 loops, best of 3: 390 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is not a function of scipy.logical_and() but instead of using the .values(). Retry the %timeit with a.values & b.values and you get the same time.

Comment: whoa indeed. Unexpected! Thanks for pointing this out. Question about the procedure, should I delete this answer now?

Answer (score 0):

I think using your mask to shrink your dataframe and then performing a more concise set of operations on that smaller frame will help a lot. Finding the indexes only to use those as lookups is unnecessary - just find the max/min outright:

```
pat1 = re.compile('apple')
pat2 = re.compile('sparta')
mask = (df['string_col1'].str.contains(pat1)) & (df['string_col2'].str.contains(pat2))

result = df.loc[mask, 'value']
difference = result.max() - result.min()
```

Comment: Where are you shrinking the df, I don't see it?

Comment: The OP is re-filtering his entire DF for each operation he performs. I perform the filter once and then operate on the smaller result set. See `result = df.loc[mask, 'value']`.

Comment: This is cheap operation, try measuring it

Comment: Did you downvote me because you attempt the same optimization but use chained indexing instead of .loc (see docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and more convoluted code? You offer the same justification for your answer that I did: "because each new filtering happens on smaller subset of original dataframe."