# Subtract 2 datetime of a same column in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have below dataframe, wanted to perform the following logic.

If the 2nd row in a case is same as the first row then do a subtract of edit(timestamp) and place it in separate column as an integer(number of days)

```
case           Edit
129038   4/3/17 19:41
129038   4/4/17 15:26
125840  5/30/17 15:24
125840  6/12/17 15:44
125840  6/23/17 16:52
125840   7/6/17 21:28
125840  8/31/17 17:26
129499   7/5/17 14:46
129499   8/23/17 9:02
129499  8/29/17 14:50
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you will want to to do this again after first iteration, to get a final table with the last timestamp minus the first one, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and try this with your dataframe df: (Adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183800/pandas-difference-between-largest-and-smallest-value-within-group)):

```
result = df.groupby('case')['edit'].agg(['max','min'])
result['diff'] = result['max']-result['min']
print(result[['diff']])
```