# How do I find the window of time between the earliest time stamp and the latest time stamp of one column and group it by another column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, window

I'm working with a large data file and I would like to find the window of time of one column from the earliest time stamp to the latest time stamp and group this by the string in another column which title. I am working in python and juypter.

Test_Ordered_at            Title
2020-04-07 15:06:00  The order is green
2020-04-07 18:56:00  The order is green
2020-04-07 15:07:00  The order is green
2020-04-07 18:55:00  The order is green 
2020-03-07 16:55:00  The membership is cancelled
2020-03-07 17:55:00  The membership is cancelled 
2020-03-07 18:55:00  The membership is cancelled

Result should be like:
Test_Ordered_at         Title 
03:50:00                            The order is green 
02:00:00                            The membership is cancelled

This is my code below

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
notmiss = df 

notmiss['Test_Ordered_At'] = notmiss['Test_Ordered_At'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
print(notmiss.head())
# Add a new column instance, this adds a value to each instance 
notmiss['instance'] = 1

# set index to time, this makes df a time series df and then you can apply pandas time series functions.
tf = notmiss.set_index(notmiss['Test_Ordered_At'], drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Difference between largest and smallest value within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183800/pandas-difference-between-largest-and-smallest-value-within-group)

Comment: try this, ```df.groupby('Title')['Test_Ordered_at'].agg(['min', 'max']).diff(axis=1)```

Comment: ^ that worked! is there a way I can average all the max time stamp? I just one to get one number and thats the average of all the max.

Answer (score 1):

You could do so using [`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Test_Ordered_at': ['2020-04-07 15:06:00','2020-04-07 18:56:00','2020-04-07 15:07:00','2020-04-07 18:55:00','2020-03-07 16:55:00','2020-03-07 17:55:00','2020-03-07 18:55:00'],
'Title': ['The order is green','The order is green','The order is green','The order is green','The membership is cancelled','The membership is cancelled','The membership is cancelled']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Test_Ordered_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Test_Ordered_at'])
print(df.groupby('Title')['Test_Ordered_at'].agg(np.ptp))

Title
 The membership is cancelled   02:00:00
 The order is green            03:50:00
```

Comment: I tried that and got this error Exception: Must produce aggregated value

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to cast `Test_Ordered_at` to datetime, please try again.

Comment: I tried the new one and got this error ValueError: Function does not reduce

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: If your dataframe `df` is as you've described this should work. I've updated my answer with the dataset I've taken from your example. Please check if there are any discrepancies with your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

1. once it's date time simple aggregate and calculate

```
data = '''Test_Ordered_at,        Title
2020-04-07 15:06:00, The order is green
2020-04-07 18:56:00, The order is green
2020-04-07 15:07:00, The order is green
2020-04-07 18:55:00, The order is green 
2020-03-07 16:55:00, The membership is cancelled
2020-03-07 17:55:00, The membership is cancelled 
2020-03-07 18:55:00, The membership is cancelled'''
da = [[i.strip() for i in l.split(",")] for l in data.split("\n")]
da
df = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])
df.Test_Ordered_at = pd.to_datetime(df.Test_Ordered_at)
df2 = df.groupby("Title")["Test_Ordered_at"].agg(["min","max"]).reset_index()
df2["Test_Ordered_at"] = df2["max"] - df2["min"]
df2.drop(columns=["min","max"])
```

**output**

```
    Title   Test_Ordered_at
0   The membership is cancelled 02:00:00
1   The order is green  03:50:00
```