# groupby calculating average with timestamp field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df:

```
user_id |  timestamp    
0      2019-04-25T13:30:18  

0   2019-04-25T13:31:40

1   2019-04-26T11:15:00

1   2019-04-26T11:15:35
```

I need groupby user_id subtracting timestamp column:

```
0 01:22

1 00:35
```

I already tried use:

```
 mean()
 transform('min')
```

and

```
transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).days)
```

but none of these worked, does anyone know how to do date-time operations on pandas?

I want to group the user_id, but in the timestamp field I need the difference between the highest and the lowest timestamp by user_id

Comment: Are there only ever 2 observations per id?

Comment: @ALollz not exactly, can be more

Comment: So in that case you still just want the difference between the max and min value within group?

Comment: I want to group the user_id, but in the timestamp field I need the difference between the highest and the lowest timestamp by user_id

Comment: may be this will help you ??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183800/pandas-difference-between-largest-and-smallest-value-within-group/40183861

Comment: I received it: DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation ptp